# Run method in base class and in addition run method in subclass

Tags: c#

I want to be able to run the method in my base class which is displaySomething()
and in addition run the method in my subclass called displaysomething()

Is this possible? How can I achieve this please?

I have a base class that looks like this

```
public class baseClass
{
    public void displaySomething()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Method from base class: display something");
    }
}
```

I have a subclass that looks like this

```
public class subClass : baseClass
{

    public void displaySomething()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Additional method to run after base class method");
    }

}
```

I have a button click event that looks like this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    subClass mySubClass = new subClass();
    mySubClass.displaySomething();
}
```

Comment: Note that it can't be done _by the caller_ - the subclass gets to decide whether or not the base class method is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the call of the overriden method of the base class in the implementation of the overriding method of the subclass, like this:

```
public void displaySomething() {
    // You can decide to call the base before, after,
    // or in the middle of your new method.
    base.displaySomething();
    MessageBox.Show("Additional method to run after running base class method");
}
```

Note that your code does not override the method, because it is not declared `virtual`. You need to declare it like this:

```
public class baseClass {
    public virtual void displaySomething() ...
}
public class subClass : baseClass {
    public override void displaySomething() ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. So I have to add the Virtual and override?

Comment: @user2320476 If you want to have polymorphic behavior (which is almost universally the purpose of having a method in the subclass with an identical signature), then the answer is "yes".